# Using tkdiff on windows with putty session

Tags: putty

When I try to execute tkdiff inside my putty session. I get this message "Application initialization failed: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable" and it hangs. Please suggest how to configure tkdiff.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a tkdiff problem. It means you don't have an X server (graphical window manager) running that putty knows about.

You have to at the very least go into putty's Connection / SSH / X11, and "Enable X11 forwarding".  However, you also have to have an X11 server running on your system, which is more complicated.

Comment: If you are running Windows then the easiest way to get an X-server is through cygwin.